# Visual Studio 2015 CE where to put "/pdbaltpath:%PDB%"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I found on MSDN a reference to using /pdbaltpath:%PDB% to remove the absolute pdb path from the executable, but I don't know which field to put this in under the linker options in Visual Studio 2015 community edition. Where does it go?

Comment: You can try putting it in the `Linker/Command Line/Additional Options` edit box.